# program that generates multiplication tables acting weird

Tags: c++, codeblocks

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx9Kl.png)

Here's the code. It's supposed to generate and output a 2D array but, for some reason, messes up the value for 9x10 (90) and causes the program to crash. I've attached a screenshot.

Any advice? Also, how can I make the numbers line up nicely into a neat grid?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int values[10][10];
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=10;j++)
        {
            values[i][j]=i*j;
            cout<<\t<<values[i][j]<<flush;
        }
    cout<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do know that indexes in arrays in C++ are zero based? So for an array of ten elements the indexes go from `0` to `9` (inclusive). If you *don't* know that then you need to [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start over.

Comment: I'm aware, but since I wanted to use the variables i and j to actually calculate the values (which go from 1x1 to 10x10) I went with i=1 and j=1.

This doesn't seem to be the cause of the error, though.

Comment: @Shehryar it is, in fact, the cause of the error. The values you show to the user (1...10) differ from the values you need to store data in the array (0..9). Fortunately one can be derived from the other, but given your current requirements they cannot be the same.

Comment: @Shehryar Why do you need an array, actually?

Comment: That *is* the cause of your error. You can't just ignore the bounds of your array because they don't suit your other purposes...

Comment: @fbrereto I changed the int i and j to start from 0 to accurately represent the index bounds--and changed the calculation to (i+1) and (j+1). Same issue, still.

Comment: @JBentley didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @LogicStuff it's just an exercise from the tutorial I'm using to learn C++

Comment: @Shehryar Since you indicated that Wanderer's answer worked, my guess is that you forgot to change the upper bound of your for loops from 10 to 9 when you made your modifications.

Comment: @JBentley strangely enough despite editing the bounds of the loop and array and modifying the calculation to (i+1)*(j+1), I had the same issue. A fresh cpp file saved the day somehow. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero based indexes, equally spaced values in console, values starting at 1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int values[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            values[i][j] = (i + 1)*(j + 1);
            cout << setw(5) << values[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Shehryar Never say never. For one thing you'll upset Justin Beiber, but more importantly, there are origin 1 programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to

```
for( int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        values[i][j] = (i + 1)*(j + 1);
    }
}
```

edited to include the body too.

Comment: But keep `(i + 1) * (j + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

arrays start at 0 not 1

```
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int values[10][10];
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=10;j++)
        {
            values[i-1][j-1]=i*j; // <<<<<<<<<<
            cout<<'\t'<<values[i-1][j-1]<<flush;
        }
    cout<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

edit: output

```
Success time: 0 memory: 3412 signal:0
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
    2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20
    3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30
    4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
    5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
    6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
    7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
    8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
    9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
    10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

Comment: Thanks. Still getting the same error. What should be 90 (for 9x10) shows 68.

When I try to output just that value separately, it shows 11.

Comment: so not the same error at all then :-). Step through the code with a debugger

Comment: i just ran the code in ideone and it works perfectly

Comment: Could it be an issue with my pc?

Comment: no - its not an issue with yr pc. post the new code in the question along with its output

Comment: typed my own code into a new CPP file and it worked. thanks!